# iPhone sideways scrolling of a div

Tags: iphone, webkit

I am coding a website for iphone.

Some of the content (images and strings I have no control over) is too wide to fit in the 320px viewport. When I first encountered this, it caused the entire page to revert to web page view (scaled small text).

So, I put the wide images in a div with CSS style="width:320px; overflow:scroll;" This stopped the page scaling but I assumed I would be ale to scroll that div horizontally to see the rest of the images (like the app store does with screen snaps). However, the scrolling just doesn't work on the ipod. (It does work on Safari in default Mac mode but not in Safari as iPhone User Agent.)

Anyway, how can I get the sideways scrolling on the ipod?

Answer (score 3):

http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-for-mobile-webkit-turns-3/16

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at the script now. I may use it but why does it take so much code to do this when it should be a simple attribute of the div? Is there not a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll with 2 fingers?

Comment: Wow, scroll with 2 fingers does work. I didn't know this and unfortunately, many of my frustrated users won't either. The app store doesn't need two finger to scroll sideways. I want to be consistent with past experience.